# how to change progressbar mode color

Tags: android

im using progressbar in my application everything is work fine is change is color below 35%  but problem is its show double effect see image https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4uUX.jpg its change its color to red but also show double effect hwo i wil change to black????

```
progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.signalLevel);
private String getSignalLevelString(int level) {
    String signalLevelString = "Weak";
    level=35;
    if (level >= EXCELLENT_LEVEL)
    {
        signalLevelString = "High";
    progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }

    else if (level <= GOOD_LEVEL)
    {
        signalLevelString = "Weak";
        progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED,  Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }

    return signalLevelString;
}
```

XML Code:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/signalLevel"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:progress="100" 
   style="@style/progressStyle"/>
```

Comment: try this in your case   ((ProgressBar)findViewById(id)).getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.MULTIPLY);

Comment: i did but mode.multiple show double effect see image http://imgur.com/SMU3xG3 i dont want  double image i want rest of progressbar black

Comment: set the progress bar background android:background="#000000"

Comment: let me know if it's work or not..

Comment: not work something is in Mode... which change effect i guesss

Comment: lets try this android:progress="0"